# Symfony2.3 - How to add a custom vendor

Tags: php, symfony, vendor, symfony-2.3

I have a Symfony 2.3 project and I would like to use a custom vendor. I know that on Symfony versions 2.1 and 2.2, you can declare vendors in the `deps` file.

But how can I declare a custom vendor in Symfony 2.3 project? There is a `composer.json` file, but I don't really understand how it works.

**EDIT**:
The custom vendor's code is located on github.

Comment: where is your custom vendor's code at? If you're using a vendor that's available on [packagist](http://packagist.org), search and find the right requirement and add it to your composer.json.

Comment: My custom vendor code is on a git repository. I found this, http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/installation.html, and trying to understnad how it works

Comment: If you already have a git repository, you should read [Packagist's documentation](https://packagist.org/about)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`composer.json` manages dependencies through the `composer` tool (which you should have [installed](http://getcomposer.org/download/)). It behaves similarly to `npm` if you have used that at all.

You can include a custom vendor in a couple of ways - although for the custom vendor code to be (auto)loaded & picked up by `composer` it will need to have a `composer.json` file.

### Packagist

If the custom vendor has successfully submitted their to [packagist](https://packagist.org/) then you life is easy, you can search for it and take note of the name (in the `<vendor>/<package>` format.

Open up your `composer.json` file and at the end of the `"require": {}` statement add your vendor. For example if our package was called `peterjmit/awesome-package`

```
// ...
"require": {
  // ...
  "peterjmit/awesome-package": "*"
},
// ...
```

You can replace the `*` with a version number if you wish. Once you have done that, you can run the `composer update` command to pull in your new package. If you only want to update the new package you can use `composer update peterjmit/awesome-package`.

Thanks to the composer autoloader, and the [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) standard, classes from the package are auto-loaded so there is no other "plumbing" for you to do.

### VCS repository

If the custom vendor is not on packagist, but does have a `composer.json` file then you can specify a custom repository to composer. You need to have the same `require` statement as before, but you need to add a new statement to `composer.json`

```
// ...
"require": {
  // ...
  "peterjmit/awesome-package": "*"
},
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "git@bitbucket.org:peterjmit/awesome-package.git"
  },
  // .. etc.
```

If the package *does not* have a `composer.json` then you can always fork it and add your own. But if the code does not conform to PSR-0 then you will have to sort out your own auto-loading strategy for the package.